# Create HyperlinkButton with text wrapping in code behind (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have the following xaml snippet that I need to create in code behind.  Is this possible to do?

```
<HyperlinkButton Name="hyperlinkButton1" NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" Margin="0" Padding="0">
     <HyperlinkButton.Template>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                <Border BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0">
                          <Image Source="/Assets/Logo.png" Margin="0"/>
                          <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Go to View.xaml" Foreground="Green"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
           </ControlTemplate>
     </HyperlinkButton.Template>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Comment: What is the a reason you need to create this in code-behind?

Comment: The hyperlinks come from a web server that holds bbcode.  I am parsing it and putting it into a wrappanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the xaml above into a long string (start with `@"` to have a multi-line string in C#) and then call `XamlReader.Load( myXamlString )`.

Alternatively, you can create the hyperlink button and set its template in code-behind. Even in that case, however, the general advice is to use XamlReader to create the template from a string.